# callback in jquery function

Tags: jquery

Can we callback jquery function with selector in another jquery function ?
Like I have two jquery functions

```
// Function 1: 
   $("#slideUp").click(function(){
      $("#testDiv").slideUp("slow",CALLBACK);
   });

// Function 2: 
   $("#slideDown").click(function(){
      // Do some stuff
   });
```

How can I call Function 2 in Function 1's callback ?

*EDIT: Adding correct terminologies ***

Can we callback one jquery listener with selector in another jquery listener ?
Like I have two jquery listener

```
// Listener 1: 
   $("#slideUp").click(function(){
      $("#testDiv").slideUp("slow",CALLBACK);
   });

// Listener 2: 
   $("#slideDown").click(function(){
      // Do some stuff
   });
```

How can I call `Listener 2` as `Listener 1` callback ?

I want to execute click listener of `slideDown` once `testDiv` is silde up.
Thank you Spycho.

~Ajinkya.

Comment: What does `Function 1:` replace?

Comment: What does the code for `CALLBACK` look like?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to trigger a click on the element with ID `slideDown` then use `$("#slideDown").click()` in your callback function. That will trigger the event handler for that element.

Comment: Means can I replace `CALLBACK` in `Function 1` with `$("#slideDown").click()` ?

Comment: Almost. `CALLBACK` has to be a function, so you can replace it with `function() { $("#slideDown").click() });`. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/sJ7bd/

Comment: @James: I have updated my question with correct terminologies (hopefully). Please check it.

Comment: @Ajinkya - What do you mean? I have already told you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you want, because "Function 2:" is not a function, it is a statement.

Either you want:

```
$("#testDiv").slideUp("slow",function() {
    $("#slideDown").click();
});
```

to trigger the `click` event.

Or

```
$("#testDiv").slideUp("slow",function() {
   $("#slideDown").click(function(){
      // Do some stuff
   });  
});
```

to assign a `click` handler.

Comment: @Felix: Sorry for confusing you.I want call `Function 2 ` as `Function 1` callback.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Still confusing. What you refer to as `Function 2` is **not** a function, it is a function *call*.

Comment: @Felix: Sorry again. I want to execute bunch of line I mentioned as `Function 2` after line  `$("#testDiv").slideUp("slow",CALLBACK);` in block `Function 1`.

Comment: @Ajinkya, do you mean that you only want to bind the click handler to #slideDown once #testDiv has slid up?

Comment: @Spycho: I want to execute #slideDown click handler once #testDiv has slid up. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Felix,Spycho: I have updated my question. Hope it will avoid confusion.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Yeah, it would be the first part of my answer... but you already got it anyway :)

Comment: @Felix: Ya I checked it later. I really appreciate your patience for bearing my confused thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Function 2 isn't a callback, it's an invocation of jQuery that *registers* a callback.  You need to create an accessible *reference* to f2's callback function.

Assuming that your intent is for `f2` to be invoked after the `slideUp` animation has finished, try:

```
function f1() {
    $("#testDiv").slideUp("slow", f2);
}

function f2() {
    // do some stuff
}

$('#slideUp').click(f1);
$('#slideDown').click(f2);
```

**EDIT** this is technically cleaner than triggering a new event, since all it does is use `.slideUp's` built-in "completion callback" functionality passing a direct function reference, rather than futz around injecting stuff into the event queue.

Answer (score 1):

Try .trigger()
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

In your case,

```
// Function 1:
$("#slideUp").click(function(){
  $("#testDiv").slideUp("slow", function() { $("#slideDown").trigger('click') } );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W8yZL/) what you are after?

It defines a callback function which is called both when #slideDown is clicked and when #testDiv has finished sliding up.

---

#### Update

To call the handler without defining a function elsewhere, you could 'trigger' the event that the hanlder is listening for e.g. `$("#slideDown").click();`.

Comment: Is it any other to do the same without defining `function callback()console.log('callback');}` ?

Comment: @Ajinkya, You need to define the callback somewhere... you can do it as an un-named function passed in to the click function (`$('.something').click(function(){});`) and then trigger that event when you want the callback to execute (`$('.something').click()`). However, with this approach, you will also end up executing all other handlers bound to the click of that element (and potentially the default action).

Comment: Thanks man for understanding my confused thoughts and helping me out.